# How to perform POST request involving JSONObject in java-jersey?

Tags: java, http, jersey, http-post

I have the following code to create a JSON object:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

//response is the value of some GET request I performed before
JSONObject root=new JSONObject(response.readEntity(String.class));  

//url is assigned to URL to which I wanted to POST.
WebTarget target2=client.target(url);

Response response2=target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
response2.post(*what goes here*);
```

What do I need to put inside that last `post`?

Comment: I have reformatted your code so that it is easier to read on this site.   Now none of the lines scroll off the screen so your comments are easy to see and read.   I also removed "thank you" because such pleasantries are not necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Inside the post function what exactly should be written."

Look at the [`SyncInvoker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html) API. Look at the different `post` methods. You will choose one of these, depending on what type of response you want.

The [`Entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html) argument can simply be written as [`Entity.json(yourRequestObject)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#json%28T%29), which automatically configures the request as `Content-Type:application/json`

Comment: Hey,If I have any error in the request(POST) data,how can I find the error?Thank you

Comment: Ya I found it,It took more time to execute and it displayed the error directly